# How to download Excel file using Angular js and REST Api

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

**Angular JS Code**:

```
$scope.getExcelDownload = function(index,basketid,brokerid,tradeDate,serverid,transid) {            
    var myformid = 'ExcelForm' + index;
    ExcelDownload.get({brokerid : brokerid,basketName : basketid,appl : 'abc',param : 'excel',tradedate:tradeDate,transactionID:transid,serverid:serverid},function(data, headers){
        alert("Success");
         var response = {};
        response.data = data;
        response.headers = headers();


        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/octet-stream;base64"});
         var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(objectUrl);
            saveAs(blob, "myfile.xls");
    },function(errResponse) {
        alert("failure");

    });

}
```

**REST WEBSERVICE**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getexcel/{brokerid}/{basketName}/{appl}/{param}/{tradedate}/{transactionID}/{serverid}", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable("brokerid") String brokerid,@PathVariable("basketName") String basketName,@PathVariable("appl") String appl,@PathVariable("param") String param,@PathVariable("tradedate") String tradedate,@PathVariable("transactionID") String transactionID,@PathVariable("serverid") String serverid){
        ResponseEntity respEntity = null;
        OrdersDownload orders = new OrdersDownload();

        if(param.equalsIgnoreCase(EXCEL_OPTION)){
            log.finest("ExcelDataController@getFile selected option :" + param);
            byte[] reportBytes = orderDownloadService.doGet(brokerid, basketName, appl, param, tradedate, transactionID, serverid);

            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            responseHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", String.valueOf(String
                    .valueOf((new StringBuffer("attachment; filename=\""))
                            .append(
                                    StringUtils
                                    .replace(basketName, ":", ""))
                                    .append("_orders.xls\""))));
            responseHeaders.add("Content-Type",MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);

            //return reportBytes;

            respEntity = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(reportBytes, responseHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
            return respEntity;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**Response:**
File is getting downloaded without contnet it is just printing `[object,object]` inside file.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me...

```
// Download excel template file
  $scope.downloadExcelTemplate = function () {
    CustomerService.downloadTemplate().then(function (response) {
      var linkElement = document.createElement('a');

      try {

        var fileName = response.headers('content-name');
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
        linkElement.setAttribute("download", fileName);

        var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
          "view": window,
          "bubbles": true,
          "cancelable": false
        });
        linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
      } catch (ex) {
      }

    }, function (response) {
      toastr[messageTypes.ERROR]('Something went wrong.');
      $scope.clearForm();
      $('#cl-modal-box').modal('hide');
    });

  }
```

This the php function which handles this request

```
public function downloadTemplateAction() {

        $customer = new Customer();

        $fileName = 'customer_import_template.xlsx';
        $uploadDir = $customer->getDownloadRootDir();
        $filePath = $uploadDir . '/' . $fileName;

        // Create phpexcel object to read the excel file
        $objPHPExcel = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filePath);
        // Define writer object for Excel2007 || 2010
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");

        // Set header params
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=UTF-8');
//        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $fileName);
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        header('Content-Name: ' . $fileName);

        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: What kind of data you have in your response?

Comment: I am sending path of excel file in response from where I have to download. I have update my answer with back end which sends data in response

Comment: Hi,In response from rest api i am getting follwoing data ÐÏà¡±á;þÿ þÿÿÿ Entryÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
Workbookÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿè ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ this is not readable

Comment: You have to make response in buffer format like in code
CustomerService.downloadTemplate().then(function (response) {
<downloadable-code>
 }, function (response) {